# Square Wave not generating properly usin NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio, waveform

I am using NAudio to play a Square wave. When i record that sound in audacity and check the waveform.

It is not coming properly.

**Waveform of NAudio generated sound**
[image: Waveform of NAudio generated sound]

**Waveform of Audacity generated sound**
[image: Waveform of Audacity generated sound]

Am i doing some thing Wrong ?

Code

```
sine20Seconds = new SignalGenerator()
{
    Gain = 0.5,
    Frequency = Convert.ToDouble(freqBox1.Text)                    
};
sine20Seconds.Type = SignalGeneratorType.Square;
wo = new WaveOutEvent();
wo.Init(sine20Seconds);
wo.Play();
```

Comment: Could you add the code that generates (or rather: doesn't) the square waveform data to your question?

Comment: Code added.@Paul-Jan

Comment: Thanks. In your code fragment, you init the WaveoutEvent with "sineWave". That's *not the same variable* as the sine20seconds signalgenerator you just initialized. Additionally, you are using the wrong signal generator type for a square.

Comment: Yeah in other words the code posted is very poor quality. It's embarrassing when people cannot be bothered to post the full code.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

`sine20Seconds.Type = SignalGeneratorType.Triangle;`

to

```
sine20Seconds.Type = SignalGeneratorType.Square;
```

as per [instructions here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/PlaySineWave.md)

Comment: Sorry for the wrong code, I used SignalGeneratorType.Square only and getting that result. And even if its set to triangle, output is not what it should be.

Comment: Is the output the same if you do use the Square enum? Can you make a same project or share the whole project?  Sounds like you are missing something specific because the Square enum cannot generate the pattern you are describing. If you look at the source code, this is apparently the case. Thanks

Comment: This is the only code. I run it and record it in audacity, then check the results (which i shared) . You can check and update me.

Comment: Wow thanks! You're very kind :-) Seriously though - full article is best. Since your code example is questionable, many will assume the rest of your code is too.  There is not enough context to answer your question.